# Storing shadow data

Tags: shadow-mapping, shadow

Given a 3D space and a light source, I use ray casting to determine the shadows generated in the scene. If I'm to store the shadow data (boundary of the shadow, object which cast the shadow, etc.) what is an efficient way to go about it?

Edit:

Its basically for an application where I want to be able to move the shadow around manually to see the change in the 3d objects position. Say I apply a force to the shadow of a ball, I can actually see the ball move and also the change in the shadow. So I need to be able to set up colliders for the shadow and hence need a way to be able to store the boundary of the shadow and information about the object that cast it to carry out the actions.

Comment: In my understanding, raycasting isnt very good for boundary information. Depthmaps also dont dont benefit from raycasting. Deepshadow maps might benefit from raycasting. Otherwise you would just be better of baking lightning to model uv maps or some kind of voxel tree. Possibly per vertex/face. The question is a bit hard to swallow, could you specify it a bit. Best is not defined, efficient in this case is not terribly defined either

Comment: Are you asking for something geometric such as Franklin Crow's [Projected Shadow Volumes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.424.6834)?

Comment: Please fill in the "etc" and tell us the purpose of storing the shadow data.

Comment: I apologize for being so vague.. Its basically for an application where I want to be able to move the shadow around manually to see the change in the 3d objects position. Say I apply a force to the shadow of a ball, I can actually see the ball move and also the change in the shadow. So I need to be able to set up colliders for the shadow and hence need a way to be able to store the boundary of the shadow and information about the object that cast it to carry out the actions.

Comment: Can I infer that "etc" is void ? What other information is relevant ?

Comment: @ichigo1191 your comments are giving a lot more detail than the question, which makes a big difference. I recommend you [edit] the question to include the extra detail all in one place. Comments are not guaranteed to last forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is mouse interactivity, you can do with a simple "shadow buffer", i.e. an image that holds the identity of the occluding object (if any) on every rendered pixel. You will compute this map during the casting process as you shoot the rays to the source.

In case there are several occluding objects, it is up to you to choose which one to consider (or keep a linked list of all occluding objects). If there are several sources, you can keep one map per source.

Comment: Why not trace on click? There sa really neat trick if there is less than 32-96 objects.

Comment: @joojaa: no idea what you mean.

Comment: Why make a buffer of rays? If your only interested in one ray, shoot the ray when your needing it. Its fast enough. Why shoot a shadow buffer with rays just use a separate pass and use depth maps + index color. Again you can do this on demand. If you have 3 color channels you can use a bit mask for surfaces hit tahtway you can store ALL objects in pass of ray if you must etc. Too many open variables in question to nake any meaningful impact.

Comment: @joojaa: I guess this comment belongs to the OP. I am answering the question "how to store ?".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into signed distance field textures.  They are very efficient and high quality for monochromatic images like shadows.  They work by storing a clamped, signed distance from the pixel to the shape.  Working this way, the distances play nicely with the bilinear interpolation of texture sampling, so you can have very nice results for very low resolution.  You can also give them a soft edge to have a soft shadow look.